# How to retrieve value from mongodb with await function?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to write a function which pass query and url and retrieve values from mongodb. The values must be used outside the function. How to write an await function?

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {  
  if (err) throw err;  

  var x = "1001"

  var query = ({
    "land_id": x
  }); 

  var dbo = db.db("deed");
  dbo.collection("deedusers").find(query).toArray(function(err, result) {  
    if (err) throw err;  
    else if(result.length >0)
      console.log(result);  

    var name = result[0].name;
    var email = result[0].email

    console.log(name);
    console.log(email);   

  });  
});
```

I can print name and email but cant use it outside the function. I want to use variable name and email outside the function.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this:

```js
var myFunc = async function(query) {
  var db;
  var client;
  try {
    client = await MongoClient.connect(connection string, { useNewUrlParser: true });
    db = client.db(DatabaseName);
    return await db.collection(collectionName).find(query).toArray();
  } finally {
    client.close();
  }
}
```

Now you can call `myFunc` and then get the results from the query

```js
myFunc(query).then(res => {
  console.log(res)
})
```

you can also do this:

```js
let result = myFunc(query)
result.then(res =>{
//Do something with res and then return the modified value it will pass this value in next .then
 return modifiedres
}).then(ans =>{
//Here you can again do something and return it and it will pass in next .then or do whatever you want and in last use .catch
}).catch(error =>{
 console.log(error)
})
```

Comment: That won't work, because `mongodb` doesn't support promises.

Comment: https://medium.com/@tvalletta/promises-with-the-mongodb-node-client-d30c4549028d Look at this

Comment: Yes, you're right, I was confused that in `mongodb` docs there are nothing about promises. I just test it myself and it works.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But is there a way to store it in variable and use the variable ie, not inside  myFunc(query).then(res => {   })

Comment: @GEORGEJOSE if you use await it will return a promise always and you have to consume it by .then method.I think you can use it this way and achieve your result, i have updated my answer so check it if you want something like this or explain your problem properly.